# How to convert time stamp containing T and z ( for ex - 2020-03-02T16:30:36Z) to dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: r

I am designing a Flex dashboard. One of the column in my dashboard is a time stamp whose column contains entries like 2020-03-02T16:30:36Z. I want to convert it into dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss. Please help.
I tried this but nothing happened. In-fact, the entries got removed from the flex dashboard
df$time<- as.POSIXct(df$time, 
format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz="GMT")

Answer (score 2):

`libridate`'s function as_datetime also works:

```
library(lubridate)
as_datetime("2020-03-02T16:30:36Z")
[1] "2020-03-02 16:30:36 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`anytime` package](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/anytime) can help:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime("2020-03-02T16:30:36Z")
[1] "2020-03-02 16:30:36 CST"
R> utctime("2020-03-02T16:30:36Z", tz="UTC")
[1] "2020-03-02 16:30:36 UTC"
R>
```

First, by not requiring an input format but rather by relying on a number of possibly / plausible formats it tries heuristically.  Second, by also offering to parse at UTC (and, as we do here, impose UTC for the printed format / display, which is otherwise localtime).  Third, we also have some output formats should you need them:

```
R> pt <- utctime("2020-03-02T16:30:36Z", tz="UTC")
R> iso8601(pt)
[1] "2020-03-02T16:30:36"
R> rfc2822(pt)
[1] "Mon, 02 Mar 2020 16:30:36.000000 +0000"
R> rfc3339(pt)
[1] "2020-03-02T16:30:36.000000+0000"
R> yyyymmdd(pt)
[1] "20200302"
R>
```

The underlying implementation is in C++ so it also tends to be faster than the equivalent alternatives (which require a format spec or hint).